# Comment traduire « upload » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, jargon

J'ai toujours eu de la difficulté avec ce mot. Partout où je cherche, je trouve *télécharger*, mais j'aimerais pouvoir faire la distinction entre *download* et *upload*. Il me semble que *télécharger* est très souvent associé à *download*, je me demandais donc si vous aviez de meilleures suggestions pour un verbe qui signifie l'envoi d'un fichier sur un serveur.

Comment: J'entend et utilise très souvent le verbe *envoyer*. "Envoyer un fichier" me semble tout à fait correct. En revanche, quand il faut parler plus technique (s'il s'agit de débit par exemple), l'anglicisme *upload* est très souvent utilisé en France.

Comment: Je trouve qu'il est mauvais de vouloir absolument tout franciser, on se retrouve avec des mots assez mauvais comme `téléversement`, `arrosage` ou autres `concentrateur`. Ces mots ne parleront ni au profane, ni au technicien (qui lui les utilisera en anglais).

Comment: @JulienLachal Pour moi *concentrateur* est utilisé et semble relativement clair, à l'inverse de *téléverser* dont on se demande toujours quel sens cela désigne. Dans l'intention, on comprend que les linguistes sont revenu à la métaphore du chargement des marchandises en vrac. *Verser* est le contraire de *charger*, Ok. Du coup, comme *télécharger* est généralement compris comme descendant (download), *téléverser* serait montant (upload), ce qui est contre-intuitif, car on verse un liquide/fluide vers le bas.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On voit souvent débit *descendant* et débit *ascendant* (ou *montant*) chez les fournisseurs d'accès. J'opterais donc pour « téléchargement descendant » (lorsque l'utilisateur reçoit des données) dans le cas où la précision est nécessaire et « téléchargement ascendant » pour indiquer l'autre direction (l'envoi de données).

Il [parait](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A9l%C3%A9chargement) qu'on trouve aussi « téléversement » pour distinguer du « téléchargement » habituel (descendant), mais je ne l'ai jamais entendu.

Comment: _Téléversement_ est peut-être typique du Québec

Comment: Il me semble avoir déjà entendu téléversement. Je suis également du Québec, comme les personnes qui liront ce mot. C'est probablement une bonne solution.

Comment: Je suis de France et j'ai également entendu ou lu téléversement une fois ou deux.

Comment: Je suis français et j'aime beaucoup le mot téléversement.

Comment: Je suis française et j'utilise depuis longtemps *téléverser* et *téléversement*. Je les utilise dans mes échanges oraux et écrits, y compris sur des sites internet pas uniquement fréquentés par des spécialistes en informatique.

Comment: @Laure: Et te comprend-on souvent ? Je parierais que non (et pourtant je connaissais ce mot).

Comment: Un certain fournisseur au Québec utilise les termes en aval (download) et en amont (upload).

Comment: Je suis d'accord, "télécharger" ne se traduit pas par "download". "télécharger" comprend "download" et "upload".

Comment: J'ai déjà vu "*téléversement*" en tant que traduction de upload dans un logiciel (Ubuntu One).

Comment: Je crois Wikipédia a contribué à la popularisation de « téléverser ». En revanche, je ne suis pas d'accord avec la réponse : [le descendant, c'est vers l'utilisateur](http://reseaux.orange.fr/vos-questions/adsl-vdsl2/que-veut-dire-un-debit-montant-et-un-debit-descendant). L'_upload_ est dont un téléchargement ascendant (_**up**load_).

Comment: @Chop: Ok ma réponse n'était pas complètement claire, mais c'est bien ce que je voulais dire.

Comment: Je ne me rappelle pas avoir déjà lu "téléversement", mais en Belgique on est généralement beaucoup plus souple avec l'emploi de l'anglais quand la traduction est trop périlleuse ou impossible. On parle ainsi couramment de "vitesse d'upload" et "vitesse de download" sur les pages produit des ISP. J'ai un peu tendance à croire que ceux qui comprennent de quoi il s'agit comprennent le terme upload, pour les autres peut-être être plus explicite qu'un simple mot, quel qu'il soit, serait utile ("envoi de données","envoi de fichier", ...)

Comment: @LaurentS. En France, il est coutumier de renoncer aux anglicismes. Dans le domaine de la technologie, l'Académie propose souvent des termes à utiliser à la place des anglicismes qui ont déjà eu le temps d'être proposé.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Merci pour la clarification de ta réponse. À noter que [le Wiktionnaire définit _upload_ comme un anglicisme pour « téléversement »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/upload).

Comment: Jamais entendu *téléversement* -- que je ne trouve d'ailleurs pas très beau, et que j'associerai plus au paiement en ligne. Il est vrai que les anglicismes ont tendance à envahir le vocabulaire technique. J'ai vu et entendu "mettre en ligne" -- qui n'est pas exactement une traduction mais qui finalement traduit l'intention. En général quand quelqu'un uploade un fichier, c'est pour que les utilisateurs puissent le télécharger.

Answer (score 23):

À priori, je pense comme toi que *télécharger* est le seul équivalent plus ou moins reconnu, mais qu'il évoque beaucoup plus le *download* que l'*upload*.

Personnellement, je n'hésiterais pas trop à utiliser l'atroce *uploader* (surtout qu'on néerlandais, le verbe *[uploaden](http://woordenlijst.org/zoek/?q=uploaden)* est parfaitement officiel (Le *taalunie* ayant moins de scrupules, et pas beaucoup plus de choix, il est vrai).

Si tu veux un mot plus français, une [autre réponse](http://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-1770219-equivalent-francais-du-mot-upload) à la même question propose *télédéposer* qui n'est pas si mal.

Une autre réponse plus loin sur la même page propose de faire la différence vis-à-vis de la source (*télécharger **de***) ou de la destination (*télécharger **vers***).

Je proposerais aussi *télédécharger*, vu que *décharger* est l'antonyme de *charger*, mais je crois que c'est plus confus qu'autre chose.

Comment: "Télécharger" évoque Download parce qu'il est plus souvent utilisé comme cela par l'utilisateur lambda. Mais ça ne veut pas dire qu'il a perdu le sens "upload".

Comment: "Télédéposer" me sied.

Answer (score 14):

En France, on dit en général ***télécharger*** que ce soit dans le sens montant ou descendant. On trouve quelquefois ***charger*** qui évoque spécifiquement le sens montant (sinon ce serait *décharger*, mais cela ne se dit pas pour *download*), quand on n'utilise pas *uploader*. Si on veut préciser le sens d'un téléchargement, on peut se reposer sur les prépositions (télécharger *de* (ou *depuis* l'origine *vers* la destination). Lorsque *upload* est utilisé comme adjectif, on dit souvent ***montant*** (*upload bandwidth* = *débit montant*).

La [base de données terminologique de l'UE](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/SearchByQuery.do) propose *télécharger* ou *charger*.

Le [*Grand dictionnaire terminologique*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2075523) du Québec propose *télécharger* (en précisant la direction) ou ***téléverser***. Je ne connaissais pas le mot et je ne l'aurais pas forcément compris, et d'ailleurs je trouve sa construction étrange (verser évoque quelque chose qui descend). Il propose aussi *télépartageur* pour *uploader*, ce qui est plus logique (dans le contexte spécifique du partage de fichiers bien sûr).

La base [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?sourceoverride=none&source=auto&query=upload) trouve des traductions diverses : *télécharger* domine, mais on trouve aussi *remonter* (pour un contenu abstrait comme de l'information plutôt qu'on contenu concret comme un fichier), *transférer*, *téléverser*, *charger*, et une proportion non négligeable de phrases qui sont tournées différemment en français.

Comment: Je dois avouer qu'à première vue, j'aurais interprêté *téléversement* comme « faire un paiement par internet ».

Comment: Le _verser_ c'est p-ê. inspiré de verser des documents au dossier ; [apporter](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/verser/81648?q=verser#80682). Mais je comprends le commentaire sur l'idée de verser une somme d'argent etc. Je comprendrais p.-ê. différemment _téléverser_ de _faire un téléversement_. @Benjol cc.

Comment: Comme vous j'ai lu *téléversement*, qui a visiblement été choisi comme contraire de télécharger (verser vs charger un cargaison), mais effectivement ça porte une connotation descendante. Pour ma part, je préférerais *déposer* (sur un serveur) voire télédéposer.

Answer (score 14):

Dans le monde des télécommunications (dont je fais partie), on définit *télécharger* comme n'importe quel chargement à distance. On distingue néanmoins le sens de ce chargement.

Par exemple, lorsque votre navigateur internet (Firefox, Google Chrome, etc.) contacte french.se pour afficher les dernières questions posées par les internautes, le navigateur effectue un **(télé)chargement descendant**. De façon analogue, lorsque vous mettez en ligne une photo quelconque, votre ordinateur effectue un **téléchargement montant** vers le site internet en question.

De façon plus générale, lorsqu'un système réceptionne (i.e. charge localement depuis une source distante) des informations d'un système distant, on parle de **téléchargement descendant** (*download*).

À l'inverse, lorsqu'un système émet une information vers un destinataire distant, on parle de **téléchargement montant** (ou plus rarement ascendant).

Comment: Comme les autres l'ont précisé - j'aimerais savoir s'il s'agit du monde de télécommunication français, canadien, ou franco-universel?

Comment: Je ne sais pas si le terme est utilisé au Canada. J'ai appris et utilisé ce terme en étudiant et en travaillant dans les télécoms en France.

Answer (score 8):

- Download = télécharger, téléchargement
- Upload = téléverser, téléversement

En général, on a la vieille habitude de dire "télécharger" pour les deux cas et l'on doit déduire le sens d'après le contexte.

Answer (score 4):

En France, la sécurité sociale parle de [télétransmission](https://www.ameli.fr/medecin/exercice-liberal/facturation-remuneration/teletransmission-retour-noemie/teletransmission) pour désigner l'envoi des feuilles de soins depuis l'ordinateur du médecin vers l'ordinateur de l'assurance maladie.

Answer (score 4):

As other said, *télécharger* means both upload and download. But *télécharger* is still more use for download.

So for upload, I would suggest to use *mettre en ligne*:

> J'ai **mis en ligne** ma dernière vidéo, afin que d'autres puissent la **télécharger**.
>
> I've **uploaded** my last video, so people can **download** it.

Comment: Je crois avoir régulièrement entendu la radio de Radio-Canada utiliser cette terminologie: _«Nous **mettrons** les références **en ligne** sur la page Facebook de l’émission»._ Ce n’est pas autant le processus que le résultat final qui est mis de l’avant, mais ça convient tout de même très bien.

Comment: @Feelew En France également. C'est surtout que cette expression me paraît plus naturelle, surtout pour du langage parlé, que *téléchargement montant* comme suggéré précédemment.

Comment: Oui, cette suggestion est la seule proposée jusqu'à présent qui s’insère aussi bien dans une conversation ou une phrase. J'imagine mal: _«Nous téléversons les références à l'instant»._ Mais peut-être suis-je trop vieux jeu... Je n'ai plus l'énergie des saumons! Et puis, «Nous lançons le téléchargement ascendant des références dans quelques secondes» est franchement disgracieux.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour à tous. Je veux vous faire part de mon aporie dans ce dossier, c'est-à-dire du cul-de-sac de mes réflexions, et donc de l'état de celles-ci.  J'y entre d'emblée.

A- *télé-* est inconséquent, puisqu'évident.

B-  Charger, encore évidemment, provient de *load*, et me semble être une imprécision,  même en anglais.

C-  Tout de même, Télécharger  de/vers sont simples et immédiatement applicables, dans une phrase.

D- Il semble préférable de reprendre la « néologie » à partir de l’idée…

E- Nous cherchons des mot « en sens opposés. » [sourire] - Quels termes ou racines utilisons-nous pour *Up* et *Down* dans la création de néologismes ? Aucuns ?

E- Transmettre et Transférer me semblent les termes les plus clairs, nous approchant d’une solution sans casse-tête ou jargonnage. –Je te transfère l’image, transmets-moi ton texte.

F- Le seul moment où nous voulons deux mots antonymes est… Oui, justement, quel est-il ?

G- On pourrait chercher du côté de l’opposition amont/aval.

H- Déposer est aussi prometteur comme piste de recherche, en l'adoptant pour *upload*. Mais quel est son antonyme ?

J’aurais pu tenter de répondre à mes propres questions, mais c’est que j’ai une assemblée générale annuelle à peaufiner – au plus chrisse, en québécois vulgaire…

P.S.: Le point F m'apparaît étonnamment pertinent.

~> P.P.S., Je n'ai pas mentionné que pour mon cerveau québécois, *téléverser* ne veut strictement rien dire... Vraiment, "totally blank"–Verser ?!?

Comment: _Verser_ au dossier ? Bonjour ! Pourquoi ne pas débuter par ce que vous trouvez le plus utile et intégrer les informations de votre p.s./pps directement au texte ? Vous avez deux fois la lettre E mais indépendamment, c'est difficile à lire sous cette forme et les liens entre les points sont difficiles à faire sans aucune indication etc.

Answer (score 1):

**importer / import**

Pour mon entreprise actuelle j'ai opté pour **importer**. C'est aussi la solution utilisée par d'autres, par exemple Google: Importer des fichiers et des dossiers dans Google Drive ([Version française pour l'article "Upload files and folders to Google Drive"](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424368?hl=fr)). Elle a l'avantage de faire sens immédiatement et d'éviter les anglicismes "uploader" / "upload" ou les néologismes rarement utilisés "téléverser" et "téléversement".

Answer (score 0):

Download = télécharger
Upload = déposer

Answer (score 0):

Si on veut vraiment distinguer, on peut parler de :
Charger un fichier (via le réseau)
Décharger un fichier (via le réseau)

Comme un camion en quelque sorte...

Answer (score 0):

Upload = charger, verser, mettre en ligne
versus
Download = télécharger, récupérer

Answer (score 0):

"Téléverser" me semble le mieux.

D'autant qu'à la la réflexion, le terme "ascendant" ou "montant" ne veut rien dire: deux PC identiques, qui s’échangent des fichiers sont au même niveau : 
Chaque sens étant à la fois descendant ou montant sans qu'on puissent établir de hiérarchie.
Sinon en intégrant le sens qui en fait le PC de départ des données plus haut que l'autre : il se déverse donc ...cqfd

Answer (score 0):

Télécharger = download uniquement.
Et je trouve que "téléverser" convient pour Upload

(Oui, enfin le moins "pire"?)

Answer (score 0):

Pour ma part, le contexte à une énorme importance à la traduction.  Plusieurs  traductions sont envisageables mais seront-elles toutes compréhensibles?

### Ex1

Mis en opposition (côte à côte), téléverser devient immédiatement compréhensible, et il n'y a pas plus succint selon moi

1

- En:Maximum upload quota for attachments
- Fr: Quota maximum de téléversement pour les pièces jointes

2

- En: Maximum download quota for attachments
- Fr: Quota maximum de téléchargement pour les pièces jointes

*NB- le terme de téléverser est largement utilisé par l'administration française ainsi que dans les textes de lois.  Plus un terme sera cité sur internet, plus celui-ci sera utilisé...*

### Ex2:

Isolé, cela devient plus compliqué et je préfère une alternative

- En:  Upload a document
- Fr:  Importer un document

### Ex3:

Pour un sujet technique tel qu'un débit de transfert de données, je ne ferais simplement pas de conversion et utiliserai le terme UPLOAD

Answer (score -1):

- upload = **charger**
- download = **télécharger**

Those look pretty logical for me.

Comment: Oui mais le problème de cette approche c'est l'étymologie : le préfixe *télé* signifiant"à distance", en toute logique si charger=upload alors télécharger=upload remotely.

Answer (score -1):

Download = Télécharger
Upload = Transférer

Comment: Un petit coup d’œil au dictionnaire, « Transéférer » n'existe pas !

Answer (score -2):

Depuis la création d'Arduino j'ai opté pour "téléverser" ;)

Comment: C'est un peu court comme réponse !

Comment: *Téléverser* a déjà été donné comme réponse. Bienvenue sur FL. Ce n'est pas un forum mais un site de questions/réponses. Voir le 
[Help Center](http://french.stackexchange.com/help) pour comprendre le fonctionnement.

Answer (score -3):

"Mettre en ligne" peut-être,non ?

Answer (score -3):

Download = téléchargement
Upload = Téléchargement en amont

Comment: Jamais entendu "téléchargement en amont", qui pose problème aussi car dans le langage courant "en amont" signifie "à l'avance", "en anticipation de quelquechose".