# « Téléverser », « télécharger » et « charger »

Tags: traduction, informatique

Je sais que ça c'est une question classique mais je n'arrive pas à trouver une réponse unanime. S'il existe un duplicata  je m'excuse par avance.

En anglais il y a deux verbes : *upload / download a document*.
Ces deux verbes sont toujours traduits par **télécharger** ?
Si oui, comment peut-on distinguer les deux sens différents ?

Quand peut-on utiliser **téléverser** ? Son emploi est acceptable ? Pourquoi l'emploi du mot **charger** est inapproprié ?

J'ai le même problème avec les substantifs **téléchargement/chargement**.

En plus, pourriez-vous me dire pourquoi le verbe **uploader** n'a pas été accepté ?
Ça fait quelque mois que j'apprends l'allemand et je trouve que les mots d'informatique d'origine anglaise sont plus aisément acceptés.

Comment: envoyer, mettre (sur le serveur) ? Jamais entendu téléverser...

Comment: Un doublon possible: [Comment traduire « upload » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1265/364)

Comment: Une remarque :  "duplicata" designe une copie d'un document (photocopie par ex.). Pour parler d'une question en double comme ici, on parle plutôt de "doublon".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Charger** traduit toujours **load**,

**Télécharger** traduit toujours **download**

**Téléverser** a été proposé pour traduire **upload**, mais il n'est quasiment jamais utilisé.

Tu auras sûrement la réponse pour l'usage de "uploader" dans une autre question mais pour faire simple, c'est généralement bien compris par les gens qui connaissent/s'intéressent à l'informatique, et dans le cas général on peut très bien s'en passer et l'utiliser le moins possible.

On peut utiliser "mettre" (en ligne/sur internet/sur le serveur/ etc.) dans la grande majorité des cas.

> Je te mets le document sur google drive
>
> Je suis en train de mettre le code en ligne, attends une seconde

Comment: Je constate de plus en plus l’usage de « téléverser » dans les publications de l’État. Je l’utilise aussi systématiquement dans mes supports de cours informatique, notamment pour éviter les confusions dans les transferts client/serveur, selon le point de vue de la transaction.

Answer (score 4):

charger = to load, c'est la traduction littérale

télécharger = to download/upload

par contre on utilise

**débit montant** pour **upstream**

**débit descendant** pour **downstream**

**télé-**  est le préfixe pour dire "à distance" (remote en anglais)
du coup **charger** est pour les charegments locaux et **télécharger** pour ceux à distance

j'ai du vérifier sur google translate pour upload. On me donne bien la traduction "télécharger", personnellement j'aurais utilisé "uploader" aussi pour bien faire le distinguo entre down/up.

Si tu utilises "uploader" tu seras parfaitement compris même si ce mot n'existe pas officiellement en français, et c'est le cas de pas mal de mots liés à l'informatique. Par exemple l'académie française recommande "clavarder" (contraction de clavier et bavarder) pour "to chat" (sur un salon en ligne), mais tout le monde dit "chatter", en France du moins, c'est peut-être différent dans les autres pays francophones

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre réponse. Et comment faut-il prononcer correctement uploader ?

Comment: je ne connais pas l'écriture phonétique, mais si je devais écrire le mot comme on l'entend ça donnerait quelque chose comme "euploder"

Comment: Merci encore. Cela veut dire que l'on prononcer comme en anglais (en rajoutant la terminaison -er et l'accentuation à la fin du mot ou la lettre "u" se prononce comme dans le mot usine ?

Comment: @dimitris je ne l’ai jamais entendu prononcé comme « usine », sauf peut-être par des gens totalement hermétiques à l’anglais... cela se prononce, comme beaucoup d’autres néologismes franglais techniques ou gamer (chatter, downloader, fragger, killer,...) à l’anglaise avec une terminaison francaise.

Answer (score 1):

Concernant spécifiquement *téléverser*:

*Téléverser* est un mot proposé par l'Office québecois de la langue française, et est utilisé au Québec. Il n'est quasiment pas utilisé en français d'Europe, où *uploader* est utilisé lorsque la distinction est nécessaire.

Comment: *Téléverser* est assez rare même au Québec, surtout à l'oral (même moi, qui aime bien ce terme, j'ai tendance à employer *uploader*).

Answer (score 1):

**importer** pour upload

Pour mon entreprise actuelle j'ai opté pour **importer** pour traduire "upload". C'est aussi la solution utilisée par d'autres, par exemple Google : Importer des fichiers et des dossiers dans Google Drive([Version française pour l'article "Upload files and folders to Google Drive"](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424368?hl=fr)). Elle a l'avantage de faire sens immédiatement et d'éviter les anglicismes "uploader" / "upload" ou les néologismes rarement utilisés "téléverser" et "téléversement".

Comment: Importer/exporter, pas mal mais *faire sens* est un anglicisme.